# Shrink detail view controller animated when menu slides at UISplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm working with UISplitViewController on iPad and want to override it's behavior. When user taps on bar button, there are slides menu from the left side of screen. But it overlaps detail view controller. Can I make it so the detail view controller shrinks animated when the menu appears and expands when the menu disappears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's natively possible, so I think of 2 ways of doing this

1 - try and error: study the split delegate calls to see when you should shrink the content in your detail and tune it up until it looks smooth

2 - create your own "split" controller and do all the resizing/presenting by yourself